# How to fix 'System.OutOfMemoryException' while exporting mail items from Outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm trying to build an Windows Forms application for exporting the folder structure of Outlook including the mail items to the hard drive.

```cs
private void ExportItems(MAPIFolder folder)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(ExportPathField.Text + folder.FullFolderPath);

            Items items = folder.Items;
            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int counter = 1; counter <= items.Count; counter++)
                {
                    object item = items[counter];

                    switch (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(item))
                    {
                        case "MailItem":
                            MailItem mailitem = item as MailItem;
                            mailitem.SaveAs(ExportPathField.Text + folder.FullFolderPath + @"\" + mailitem.ReceivedTime.ToOADate() + ".msg");
                            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailitem);
                            mailitem = null;
                            break;
                        case "MeetingItem":
                            MeetingItem meetingitem = item as MeetingItem;
                            meetingitem.SaveAs(ExportPathField.Text + folder.FullFolderPath + @"\" + meetingitem.ReceivedTime.ToOADate() + ".msg");
                            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(meetingitem);
                            meetingitem = null;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
                    item = null;
                }
            }

            for(int counter = 1; counter <= folder.Folders.Count; counter++)
            {
                ExportItems(folder.Folders[counter]);
            }
        }
```

This function works properly as long as the content of the Inbox is less than 1GB. If the Inbox exceeds this size, the following error message appears: 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.
All mail items up to here were correctly exported however.

I'm calling the function like this:

```cs
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder emailFolder = outlookNs.Folders[POBoxField.Text];
ExportItems(emailFolder);
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you release `mailitem`, but `item` is still referencing it, so your `ReleaseComObject` does not work as intended. You could try using `FinalReleaseComObject`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately I still get the same error.

Comment: Also I just saw you actually release `item` after the switch-case anyways. Another guess would be that it is `items` + the recursive call whcih causes your error. As you don't need it anyways anymore you could try releasing `items` after the if-clause. 
But if thats the case you could also have large enough items before reaching a folder and releasing, so you would need to check beforehead if the folder content is too big and break it into smaller parts accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to shorten this
```c#
MailItem mailitem = item as MailItem;
mailitem.SaveAs(ExportPathField.Text + folder.FullFolderPath + @"\" + mailitem.ReceivedTime.ToOADate() + ".msg");
```
that there is no 'temporary' variable is necessary?